# CouchDB over HTTPS and self-certified certificate : browsers reject it

Tags: security, ssl, https, couchdb

I've been following [these instructions](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/How_to_enable_SSL) to enable ssl on my CouchDB instance running on Windows.
I am using self-certified .pem certificate and key generated with

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

It works fine using `curl -k https://127.0.0.1:6984/`, but Chrome and Firefox react differently:

- Firefox first makes me add a security exception for the self-signed certificate, then throws a `sec_error_invalid_key`
- Chrome just throws an `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. I tried manually adding my certificate to Chrome, same result.

On rejected connections, the Erlang console shows:

```
[error] [<0.15176.0>] SSL: certify: tls_connection.erl:2286:Fatal error: decode error
```

I need access from browsers as this is a web app. Is my key and certificate generation correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution found

The mailing list [hinted](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-user/201506.mbox/browser) that the SSL implementation in Erlang might be flawed.

As per their suggestion, I am using [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) as a SSL tunnel in front of CouchDB. The client connects to stunnel over HTTPS, and stunnel communicates with CouchDB over HTTP, but since both are on the same machine it should be fine.

stunnel generates its own certificate upon install, which (for Chrome / Win7) must be added as a *trusted root certificate authority*. Also, Chrome only takes new certificates into account when you actually **exit from the menu** and relaunch - closing the window doesn't always do that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same poblem with CouchDB and self generated certificate.
I have gave up on it.

But I can suggest you to try few things:

If you are using CORS and your main site is on http, that may be the problem. Also https on main site probably does not allow CORS -
[Check here, nothing about https](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors)

Try using proxy to have all traffic coming through one address and port. That MAY help :)
If you are using only CouchDB directly, then you probably have certificate issues.

Good luck and please post back when you solve it :) I want to know for myself as well.

Comment: Thanks. For the moment my main "site" is just a local file, so no http or https. 
I have CORS enabled indeed, but direct connection to the database (https://127.0.0.1:6984/) also fails.
I'll just try with a free Comodo certificate for the moment.

Comment: Probably the local file is the problem in your case. Try some simple http server, instead of file - HFS server may do the job - http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/

Comment: I'll try this, but again, direct connection to the DB (just opening my browser and typing https://127.0.0.1:6984/) fails, which I think makes considerations of origin irrelevant.

Comment: I asked a [question](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-user/201506.mbox/%3CCAD4LyZkO756zsagXnVckRrMxYgRO%3DppR2RwLUsebYsCpOkzzfw%40mail.gmail.com%3E) on the user mailing list.